# ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller

I created the model for the ASP.NET MVC application and I tried to create the controller for it. But, I got this

[image: error]

Please advise!

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: Instead of attaching an image, type the error message. That will help other people to find the post by searching for the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You have to **build project** to add controller for new added model in solution.

Please follow below step:

1. Remove created controller for the same model if exist
2. Clear Solution
3. Build all available project in solution
4. Now add controller for the model

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. But I just name it to another name.
It works fine. I think we cant name the controller with verbs or something likes that.